# MondoDB aggregation - remapping inner documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, remap

How could I remap inner documents like this in the following example:

```
db.customers.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "First Name": "customerDetails.firstName",
            "Last Name": "customerDetails.lastName",
            "Full Name": { $concat : [ "customerDetails.firstName", " ", "customerDetails.lastName" ] }
        }
    }
]
```

)

Placing the $ like this **"$customer.firstName"** doesn't work and instead of taking the value of the inner field **firstName** basically it doesn't return anything.

Example of the structure of **customer** collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb3c41454742e0d3c9f7605"),
    "customerDetails" : {
        "firstName" : "Robert",
        "lastName" : "Green",
        "phoneNumber" : "0878712375",
        "email" : "robert.green@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "First Name": "Robert",
    "Last Name": "Green",
    "Full Name": "Robert Green"
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
    "First Name": "customerDetails.firstName",
    "Last Name": "customerDetails.lastName",
    "Full Name": "customerDetails.firstName customerDetails.lastName"
}
```

Comment: would be great if you can give sample of your documents and the current and expected output :)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Of course `$customer.firstName` does not work if the field is called `customer**Details**`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the fields with `$`, should work:

```
db.customers.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "First Name": "$customerDetails.firstName",
            "Last Name": "$customerDetails.lastName",
            "Full Name": { $concat : [ "$customerDetails.firstName", " ", "$customerDetails.lastName" ] }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "will not work"?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. It is working. I was looking on the records where these fields are not present and have wrongly assumed that it is not working. It is quite normal to be missing if they are not present.